# mysql filtering results with subquery results

Tags: php, mysql, filter, subquery

i have two tables:

> **titles**
>
> - id
> - title
>
> **entry**
>
> - id
> - entry
> - title_id
> - user_id
> - time (timestamp)

i need to check if any new entry is submitted after my last entry at that title. looking for a query which filters the updates (different from my user_id) on each title and list the result with a number included which shows the new entries.

---

### **Example**

**titles**

```
id | title

1 | Cars
2 | Computers
```

**entry**

```
id | entry    | title_id | user_id | time
1  | bmw      | 1        | 1       | 1418595811
2  | mercedes | 2        | 2       | 1418595812
3  | ibm      | 2        | 2       | 1418595813
4  | hp       | 2        | 3       | 1418595814
5  | dell     | 2        | 1       | 1418595815
6  | acer     | 2        | 3       | 1418595816
7  | asus     | 2        | 4       | 1418595817
8  | toshiba  | 2        | 4       | 1418595818
9  | ferrari  | 1        | 3       | 1418595819
10 | toyota   | 1        | 4       | 1418595820
11 | honda    | 1        | 2       | 1418595821
```

**Expected results:**

**if user_id=1 ->**

```
Cars (3)
Computers (3)
```

**if user_id=2 ->**

```
Cars (0)
Computers (5)
```

**if user_id=3 ->**

```
Cars (2)
Computers (2)
```

as seen above, [user_id=1] submits a car (bmw). after that, other users submitted entries to that title. i need a query for new submissions for each title after user's last submission. (using the time field) 
only need is if there is new submission. if so, how many?

i need something like this:

```
select count(entry) 
from entry where time>last_entry_time[user_id] 
left join titles 
where title.id=entry.title_id
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, could you add some sample data and the desired results. If you could make a sqlfiddle also, that would be great.

Comment: just gave an example

Comment: Why is it only 1 computer for `user_id = 3`? After he submitted `hp`, user 1 submitted dell, user 4 submitted asus and toshiba, so it should be 3.

Comment: Why is it `Cars (4)` for `user_id = 1`? The only cars entered after that are the last 3 rows.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question about user 3, I was using his first entry, not last. But it still should be 2 computers, because user 4 submitted asus and toshiba.

Comment: I've corrected the counts. 
We dont have to list 0 counts.

Filterings must be based as "user_id" and "counts>0".
and result fields must be: "title" and "number (new entries count)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it for all users:

```
SELECT e1.user_id, t.title, COUNT(e2.id) AS count
FROM titles AS t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, title_id, MAX(time) AS last_entry
           FROM entry
           GROUP BY user_id, title_id) AS e1
ON t.id = e1.title_id
LEFT JOIN entry AS e2 ON e2.title_id = e1.title_id AND e2.user_id != e1.user_id AND e2.time > e1.last_entry
GROUP BY e1.user_id, t.id
ORDER BY e1.user_id, t.title
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88aacd/9)

To do it for a specific user:

```
SET @user_id = 1;

SELECT t.title, COUNT(e2.id) AS count
FROM titles AS t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, title_id, MAX(time) AS last_entry
           FROM entry
           WHERE user_id = @user_id
           GROUP BY title_id) AS e1
ON t.id = e1.title_id
LEFT JOIN entry AS e2 ON e2.title_id = e1.title_id AND e2.user_id != @user_id AND e2.time > e1.last_entry
GROUP BY t.id
ORDER BY t.title
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88aacd/35)

Comment: sorry for my counting mistakes. approach is correct, but there is no variable in your query. We need to filter the results for each user_id. (it is a session variable) 
so there should be a "where user_id='$_SESSSION["user_id"]" in the query.

Comment: I've added the single-user version.

Comment: If you don't want to list zero counts, change `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am following your question correctly. Try this

```
select e.id, e.tittle_id, e.user_id from entry e 
       where e.id not in(
                        select e.id from entry e, titles t where t.id = e.id
                        )
```

Comment: this is not the solution i need. please check the example i gave.